# Understanding a lambda function reformatting for closure

Tags: python, lambda, closures

I had an issue recently where I was using a lambda function within a for loop for pyqt with .connect. This caused issue with closure in the lambda function, I was able to resolve it using functools, but after a little bit more research I discovered I could use a slightly different piece of code that does not require importing functools.

An example code using the format:

```
for i in range(0,len(items)):
     items[i].connect( ( lambda i: lambda: func(i) )(i) )

def func(i):
    print('i value ' + str(i))
```

I am not sure why this works.

I have tried doing

```
for i in range(0,len(items)):
     items[i].connect( lambda i=i: func(i) )

def func(i):
    print('i value ' + str(i))
```

and this only gave the first value of i. The first example works exactly how I want but I do not understand what it is doing. From my understanding it returns a function evaluated with i before it is called, but then I dont understand what the (i) outside the lambda parenthesis does. I also dont understand why the second example doesnt work for me.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In [Python](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/function.html) default values such as `i=i` in the definition of the lambda in your second example are only evaulated once when the function definion is evaluated (not everytime the statement is interpreted). It means that `i` is assigned on the first iteration and then never changes.

In your first example it works because the lambda is defined without any default value and a new lambda definition is evaluated on every iteration of the loop. The bracket is used because you executing the outermost lambda on every iteration passing it `i` which returns the innermost lambda. It is easier to read if different variable names are used in each closure:

```
for i in range(0, len(items)):
     items[i].connect( ( lambda x: lambda: func(x) )(i) )
```